# How to embed the 'To:' field into my email signature in Gmail compose?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email, email-signature

**Is it possible to copy the contents of the 'To:' field into my signature when composing new mail?**

I would prefer to use Gmail's web-based interface (Browser Extension/User JavaScript/GreaseMonkey script?)

The reason I would like to do this is to [pre-populate form fields when people click links](http://youtu.be/Oh3ZKqyFEO8) in my email signature.